# SQL query group by results

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate, select, group-by

Im quite new for all the hibernate and SQL scopes, so forgive me for the silly question.

I want to make a sql query using hibernate which will group all the results by the groupUserName.

I have the following tables in my DB:

ms_GroupUser:

```
+-------------+---------------+----------+---------+
| groupUserId | groupUserName | password | groupId |
+-------------+---------------+----------+---------+
|           1 | Alice         | 123456   |       1 |                
|           2 | BOB           | 654321   |       1 |
|           3 | BOB           | 654321   |       2 |
|           4 | Charlie       | 654321   |       1 |
+-------------+---------------+----------+---------+
```

ms_Group:

```
+---------+-----------+--------+----------------+------------+
| groupId | groupName | system | systemHostName | systemPort |
+---------+-----------+--------+----------------+------------+
|       1 | TEST      | FOO    | 1.1.1.1        |       8080 |
|       2 | TEST2     | FOO    | 1.1.1.1        |       8080 |
+---------+-----------+--------+----------------+------------+
```

My Query is:

```
SELECT groupt.groupname, 
       usert.groupusername 
FROM   ms_group AS groupt, 
       ms_groupuser AS usert 
WHERE  groupt.groupid = usert.groupid 
       AND usert.password = '654321' 
GROUP  BY usert.groupusername
```

I expect it will bring me back as a result this bag:

> BOB -> TEST, TEST2.
>
> Charlie -> TEST.

What it is actually bring back is:

> BOB -> TEST.
>
> Charlie -> TEST.

Where is TEST2?

Can you please help me? am I miss understood something?

Thank you very much!

Comment: First of all consider naming your table something other than `Group`; that's a reserved word.

Comment: In such examples you may give an SQL Fiddle. Link is here http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: That is not the actual table name. It's just for easing the description of my entities in the question.  How is it helping me to resolve the problem?

Comment: Instead of it helping you resolve the problem its making it complicated for even the readers to understand in order to try to help you

Comment: Edited as requested. Is it better now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT groupUserName,groupName 
FROM ms_GroupUser u, ms_group g
WHERE g.groupId=u.groupId
AND u.password=654321
```

**Output**

```
| GROUPUSERNAME | GROUPNAME |
|---------------|-----------|
|           BOB |      TEST |
|           BOB |     TEST2 |
|       Charlie |      TEST |
```

**[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0c35e/10)**

**Edit**

Based upon your question in comments

```
SELECT groupUserName,GROUP_CONCAT(groupName)
FROM ms_GroupUser u, ms_group g
WHERE g.groupId=u.groupId AND u.password=654321 
GROUP BY groupUserName
```

**Output**

```
| GROUPUSERNAME | GROUP_CONCAT(GROUPNAME) |
|---------------|-------------------------|
|           BOB |              TEST,TEST2 |
|       Charlie |                    TEST |
```

**[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0c35e/13)**

Comment: Ok thanks! Now I want to aggregate those results under the groupUserName as you written. I mean that I will have 1 'BOB' with ('TEST' and 'TEST2') and 1 'Charlie' with ('TEST').  Is it possible?

Comment: Thank you very much! Can't vote up as i don't have enough reputation :(

Answer (score 0):

Just simply add "groupt.groupName" in the group by. So the code will become like this

```
SELECT groupt.groupName,
       usert.groupUserName
FROM   Group1 AS groupt,
       GroupUser AS usert
WHERE  groupt.groupId = usert.groupId
AND    usert.password = '654321'
GROUP  BY groupt.groupName,
       usert.groupUserName;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.groupUserName,B.groupName
FROM ms_GroupUser A LEFT JOIN ms_Group B
ON A.groupID=B.groupID
```